# setTimeOut make alternate text for a jQuery ToolTip

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

while trying to learn some client side programming, i am implementing
a alternate tool-tip,  on a `span` within a `div` , i am having a little problem to make the switch with java script for-loop

what is the proper way ?

***html***

```html
<p id="TargetP">some initial text</p>
<br />
<input type="button" id="turnOn" value="hit it">
```

***javascript***

```javascript
var texts = [];

texts.push("text one");
texts.push("text two");

$('#turnOn').on("click", function() {
    myTimer();
});

function myTimer() {
    var m = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        m = (i % 2);
       setTimeOut(function() {
            alternateTT(m)
        }, 1000);
    }
}

function alternateTT(itemNo) {
    var target = $('#TargetP');

    $(target).text(texts[itemNo]);

}
```

Comment: Can you put your script on jsfiddle.net and describe what it is supposed to do that it is not?

Comment: @JbobJohan first inside myTimer you set a timeout for wich as first parameter you create an anonymous function that call another function, please choose one, or you put all inside your anonymous function or set the first parameter as a simple call to alternateTT. Second, could you explain in more detail what you are trying to do?

Comment: @mplungjan http://jsfiddle.net/rbanay/eaLYP/6/embedded/result/

Comment: @HMarioD http://jsfiddle.net/rbanay/eaLYP/6/

Comment: @JbobJohan You don't ask me for an advice, I know, but I'll give one: Please forget jquery until you feel very confortable with plain javascript, go step by step, you are trying to do many things, timers, set css styles, anonymous functions, all in one.

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code will not work as you expect:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

  m = (i % 2);
  setTimeOut(function() {
    alternateTT(m)
  }, 1000);

}
```

By the time your timeout function has been called, it will be in the context of the final loop. Thus `m` will be equal `10 % 2` in every call.

You you want to pass an explicit variable to the timeOut function you can do it like this:

```
var param = 1;
setTimeOut(function(param) {
  alternateTT(param)
}, 1000, param);
```

Comment: just because i didn't put it within SetTimeOut anonimus ? or it will not matter ? ... this is a little updated link forgot the arrow for the tooltip 
http://jsfiddle.net/rbanay/eaLYP/8/embedded/result/

Comment: @JbobJohan Updated with how to pass the variable properly. Hope that helps :)